# Can a wizard use his familiar's senses to enlarge his "you can see" area?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, familiars, vision-and-light

I am thinking about a wizard who has a rat familiar (from the [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) spell), and has the [*misty step*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/misty-step) spell prepared. Can he use his familiar's senses to teleport into another room (where the familiar is hiding) by looking through the eyes of the rat and casting *misty step*?

The wizard could use his action to switch to the familiar's senses and then use his bonus action to cast the spell. This would greatly reduce the "blind and deaf" time he experiences from doing this.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, you can teleport to somewhere your familiar sees provided that you are *currently* seeing through it's eyes.

From the Find Familiar spell:

> ...as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes... (PHB 240)

If you've taken the action to see through your familiar's eyes, and *then* cast Misty Step, then yes, you can teleport to somewhere your familiar can see, *provided* that it's not more than 30' from your current location.

Comment: Correct. Relevant Sage Advice that uses this exact example: https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/04/09/targeting-spellsclear-path-can-i-target-across-wall-of-force/

Comment: This answer could be edited to include "clear path to target" rule. Is the familiar origin of the Misty Step spell or is it still the caster (since range is self)? Or, does "teleport" word in the _Misty Step_ description implicitly waive the "clear path to target" requirement?