# Can a familiar be used to satisfy the 30-foot requirement of the spell Locate Creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, divination

A wizard has seen through her familiar's eyes an NPC who was within 30 feet of the familiar, but more than 30 feet away from the wizard. Can the spell [*locate creature*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/locate-creature), cast by the aforementioned wizard, be used to locate this NPC?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: [Can a wizard use his familiar's senses to enlarge his “you can see” area?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51240/can-a-wizard-use-his-familiars-senses-to-enlarge-his-you-can-see-area)

Comment: I assume the familiar is from the *find familiar* spell (in case it matters)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the spell description for [Locate Creature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/locate-creature):

> so long as you have **seen** such a creature up close--within 30 feet--at least once.

The description for [Find Familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) says:

> Additionally, as an action, you can **see through your familiar's eyes** and hear what it hears

So as long as you're within 100 ft of your familiar, you can use its senses. So now it's a question of the quality of the familiar's sight. Can it see the target? It it obscured? In darkness but your familiar lacks darkvision? Blurred? Or any other factor?

So as long as it can see the creature and is within 30 ft of the familiar, then you have seen the creature while you were within 30 ft and therefore the spell should have no issue.

Comment: I believe that you can see and hear through your Familiar at any distance, only the telepathy has a 100 ft. range. (although I can't find that question now, if it was asked here)

Comment: @Mark, the exact wording is, "While your familiar is within 100 feet of you, you can communicate with it telepathically. Additionally, as an action..." Since the paragraph starts with "within 100 feet" it would be implied that both the telepathy and seeing through the senses are restricted. The Warlock Invocation _Voice of the Chain Master_ states, "You can communicate telepathically with your familiar and perceive through your familiar’s senses as long as you are on the same plane of existence." This clearly combines both features together with regard to distance.