# Is it possible to cast spells on places that can be seen through a familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, spellcasting, line-of-sight

Is it possible to cast spells on places that can be seen through a familiar?

A wizard is inside a room and their familiar is outside of it. An enemy is also outside, in front of the familiar. Would the mage be able to cast, for example, [*frostbite*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/frostbite) on that target?

> You cause numbing frost to form on one creature that you can see within range [...]

on that target? I'm aware looking through your familiar is an action, but let's assume the wizard has multiclassed into a fighter and has Action Surge.

Comment: Haste additional action does not allow you to cast a spell, nor to look though your familiar eyes . It is better to assume that wizard multiclassed into fighter and has Action Surge.

Comment: Also related: "[Can a wizard use his familiar's senses to enlarge his "you can see" area?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51240)"